# Select Distinct for multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a problem here, I need to do a query that is like this following :

```
  select client.name, client18n.display_name
        FROM Client client          
        JOIN TEAM team on (client.id = team.client_id)
        JOIN TEAM_KGK_USER members on (members.team_members_id = team.id)
        JOIN USER users on (users.id = members.user_id
        JOIN CLIENT_I18N client18n on (client.id = client18n.client_id)
        Where users.id = @userId
```

The main idea of the query is, I need to return all clients given my user id, because the user is part of a multiple teams, and each team has one client that owns this team. but I can not return duplicate clients, so I was trying to use the distinct, but than I have few problems:

- One Client can own multiple teams that the user is a member
- Another where clause is that I need to get the locale from the Client_I18N, for a given locale ID that the user can pass into this query, but for example I can pass fr_FR but if does not exist for that client I need to return the display name for en_US as a fall back
- I need to take in account that the query will have max and off set
- I need to order by the clientI18n.display_name

I am using Oracle database, to illustrate my problems here we go:

Imagine user : John is member of team A, team B, team C and team D

so the respective clients of these teams are:

Team A : ClientA
Team B : ClientA
Team C : ClientB
Team D : ClientC

for the clients they have multiple values in the ClientI18N:

ClientA: ClientA_US
ClientA: ClientA_FR

ClientB: ClientB_US
ClientB: ClientB_FR

and go on...

so if I look for the user John

Will return twice ClientA for me even if I use distinct, because I will be distinct into client.name and client18n.display_name.

I tried to return than just the client.name as it is a unique value but I need to order By the client18n.display_name, because if i don't the offset won't work.

this is what i get when I run the query for example:

```
  NAME                  DISPLAY_NAME  
  Client_38276QVAAU3    GTA_38276QVAAU3
  Client_38276QVAAU     GTA_38276QVAAU
  Client_38276QVAAU     el cliente!
  Client_38276QVAAU3    der client!
  Client_38276QVAAU2    le client!
  Client_38276QVAAU2    GTA_38276QVAAU2
```

as you can see even if I use distinct will return duplicate client name

Comment: You are going to need to provide the query you really want to run.  Sample data, desired results could help explain why `select distinct` -- the obvious solution -- doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Also, it's always a good idea to include the relevant RDBMS tag, as well as the specific version tag you are working with.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Wrt the locale fallback from `client_i18n`, you could use *inner join*  for `en_US` and *left join* for the user's locale choice, coalescing `display_name` in the select part ( `select ..., coalesce(ci_user.display_name, ci_dflt.display_name) from ... join client_i18n ci_dflt on ( ci_dflt.client_id = client.id and ci_dflt.locale_id = 'en_US' ) left join client_i18n ci_user on ( ci_user.client_id = client.id and ci_user.locale_id = @localeId ) ...`. As for the remainder of your question, it's unclear what you are asking and why you want to avoid `select distinct`.

Comment: I am working with Oracle, I don't want to to avoid distinct, actually I would need distinct because if I select for a user that has multiple teams like , team a and team B and both teams are owned by the same clients so will return duplicate client for me.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: You can use group by in the query and using a select to wrapper the result and use the distinct there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I found this solution, using union

```
 select client.name,client18n.display_name ,client18n.locale_id
        FROM Client client            
        JOIN TEAM team on (client.id = team.client_id)
        JOIN TEAM_USER members on (members.team_members_id = team.id)
        JOIN USER users on (users.id = members.user_id)
        JOIN CLIENT_I18N client18n on (client.id = client18n.client_id)
    where client.name not in ( Select distinct cli.name 
       from CLIENT cli 
        where client18n.locale_id in ('en_US','fr_FR') group by cli.name having COUNT(*) > 1) and client18n.locale_id  in ('en_US','fr_FR')
    union Select c.name,i18n.display_name ,i18n.locale_id
            FROM Client c  
            JOIN CLIENT_I18N i18n on (c.id = i18n.client_id)
            JOIN TEAM t on (c.id = t.client_id)
            JOIN TEAM_USER tu on (tu.team_members_id = t.id)
            JOIN USER u on (u.id = tu.user_id)
    where i18n.locale_id  = 'fr_FR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select client.name, client18n.display_name 
 from (select client.name, client18n.display_name
    FROM Client client          
    JOIN TEAM team on (client.id = team.client_id)
    JOIN TEAM_KGK_USER members on (members.team_members_id = team.id)
    JOIN USER users on (users.id = members.user_id
    JOIN CLIENT_I18N client18n on (client.id = client18n.client_id)
    Where users.id = @userId
    order by client18n.display_name) 
    group by client.name
```